# How do you handle the writing-mode property in Safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, webkit

In Chrome and Firefox, the `writing-mode` CSS property is handled as the documentation states. In Safari, `writing-mode` is seemingly ignored. I have tried `-webkit-writing-mode` to no avail.

Example code:

```css
p {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Guest</p>
```

The expected output would be text that reads like this:

[image]

However in Safari (tested on iPhone 11), the writing mode just writes upside-down. Has anyone encountered this/figured out a workaround? Simply replacing the `writing-mode` property with just a `transform` will not work - I need to reformat the `width` of the element.

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone with iOS 17.3

Comment: Fine for me on an iPad IOS 16.7.4